# mailjet for codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, mailjet

I have been following this documentation here:

https://www.mailjet.com/docs/code/php/codeigniter

In my config folder I created a php file as shown above like this:

```
   <?php  if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

$config['protocol'] = 'smtp';
$config['smtp_host'] = 'ssl://in.mailjet.com';
$config['smtp_port'] = '465';
$config['smtp_user'] = 'API key';
$config['smtp_pass'] = 'Pass Key';
$config['charset'] = 'utf-8';
$config['mailtype'] = 'html';
$config['newline'] = "\r\n";

?>
```

But I am still getting the following error:

```
An Error Was Encountered
Non-existent class: Email
```

When I try to load the lib like this in a controller:

```
$this->load->library('email');

$this->email->from('your_sender@address.com', 'You');
$this->email->to('recipient@example.com');
$this->email->subject('My first email by Mailjet');
$this->email->message('Hello from Mailjet & CodeIgniter !');

$this->email->send();
```

Cheers.

Comment: if you go in your `system/libraries` folder, is the `Email.php` file present?

Comment: yes it is . Do i have to modify it

Comment: No, you wouldn't have to modify it. Can you maybe post your whole controller so we can see maybe there's a different problem?

Answer (score 0):

You haven't got any file Email in System directory